# Desktop icon in Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os

How can I create desktop shortcuts for any application in Elementary Freya os? 
If I try to drag and put in desktop, my cursor changes — then how can I get back my mouse pointer without logout or restart?

Answer (score 0):

You can desktop shortcut by installing the Nautilus file manager.

1. Install Nautilus without all the related Gnome packages and dconf-editor, by running the following command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nautilus dconf-tools
   ```
2. Edit the following config entries by running `dconf-editor` in terminal or starting dconf-editor from Slingshot:

   ```
   org.gnome.nautilus.desktop
   ```

   Check entries you'd like to see on the desktop

   ```
   org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere
   ```

   Add `nautilus -n` so the entry should look somewhat like this:

   ```
   ['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent', 'nautilus -n']
   ```

   Run `nautilus -n`

   ```
   org.gnome.desktop.background
   ```

   Tick the show-desktop-icons box

Doubled mouse cursor is a bug that affects the Ubuntu lts-utopic hardware enablement stack (which is what elementary OS Freya uses). You can see the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625).

If you experience the bug, you can reset your cursor by logging out or changing TTYs (Ctrl + Alt + Fn).

**Source:** [elementary OS at stackexchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-cant-i-place-files-on-the-desktop-by-default-and-how-can-i-get-this-featur)